# In phpmyadmin, how would I link two specific rows to each other from two different tables inside a single database and keep it automated?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables within a single phpmyadmin database- one that stores basic user account info when they sign up (username, email, etc.) and another that stores whatever the user types in the text field where they input the names of their classes but also takes the username from the first table and stores it in another row inside the second table next to all the classes. The first table does what its supposed to and the user data appears there after they click sign up. After the user clicks sign up, they are directed to the classes page where they type the data for the second table. However after you click submit, there is an "object not found" error message and the second table is completely empty. Not even the username from the first table appeared within the second. For reference- inside the URL of the webpage whatever the user typed into the class boxes appears, however the end of the URL it says "submit=".

I tried searching for a few hours but really couldn't find a solution (hence what brought me here). I tinkered with my code a lot, but still couldn't figure out the issue. From what I could tell everything seemed to be right- but obviously the result wasn't. I had my connection file that connects my code to the phpymadmin database, my HTML file that provides the basic text layout which must be working fine since everything appears, and finally my file that provides the backend mechanics written exclusively in PHP- which is where I'm guessing the problem(s) most likely is/are. I've tried several functions for hours to no avail, watched videos to try to get a better idea but still cannot change the result- not even the error "object not found". I also made it so that the user has to retype their username on the classes page, which also ended with the exact same result. For reference, I am using sublimetext3, the latest version of XAMPP (Running Apache and MySQL) which comes with PHPmyadmin (where my database and tables are that store user info).

This is my backend PHP code (I have some required files that define the buttons, and names like "class1".

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $box1 = $_GET['class1'];
    $box2 = $_GET['class2'];
    $box3 = $_GET['class3'];
    $box4 = $_GET['class4'];

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $userCheck = username_verify($username, $row['uid']); 

    if ($userCheck == true) {
        header("Location: ../class_result.php?");
    exit();
}
```

/n order to recreate the text fields the user types into known as "classes" see the code below (NOTE THIS IS A SEPARATE FILE):

```
<form action="classcreation.inc.php" method="GET">

<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" name="class1" placeholder="">
<input type="text" name="class2" placeholder="">
<input type="text" name="class3" placeholder="">
<input type="text" name="class4" placeholder="">

<input type="text" name="class5" placeholder="">
<input type="text" name="class6" placeholder="">
<input type="text" name="class7" placeholder="">
<input type="text" name="class8" placeholder="">

<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

//And finally my connection file- though I am almost certain this is correct, I'm posting it in order for answerers to see that I have established a connection and the method in which I did so:

```
$dbservername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbservername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);
```

As previously stated, after the user clicks submit on the classes page, whatever they inputted in the text fields known as "classes", should appear in the corresponding second table. In addition to that, the second table should receive the username of the user typing the information- which was already collected from the first table. But instead the second table is completely empty. Furthermore, they are to be directed to another page that for now just says "Welcome!" (using simple echo statements for the message), but instead receive an "object not found error. Whether the last part is related to the database emptiness I am not 100% sure, but I believe that it is.

Comment: You never wrote a SQL query.

Comment: What would you write as your SQL query in this situation? I tried "SELECT users.uidUsers; INSERT INTO user_classes.usernames;" to no avail. Am I missing a simple syntax error or is my entire logic there wrong?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never executed a SQL query with the class data.

I recommend changing the HTML so you name all the class input fields `name="class[]"`. This will make `$_GET['class']` an array that you can loop over.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $username = $_GET['uid'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result_user);
    $userCheck = username_verify($username, $result_user);

    if ($userCheck) {   
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_classes (username, class) VALUES (?, ?)");

        $class = null;
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $class);
        foreach ($_GET['class'] AS $class) {
            if (!empty($class)) { // skip empty input fields
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, change the table and column names in the query to match your actual table.

When creating the form from the login page, you can fill in the `uid` input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="uid" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" placeholder="Username">
```

However, putting the username in the form is a bad idea, since the user can edit it to submit data for a different user. Making it readonly or hidden doesn't help much, since the user can still change it using Developer Tools.

It would be better if the login page put it in a session variable, and used that on all subsequent pages. This can't be modified by the user.

Comment: Right but then even after I make the SQL query with the class data, I still have to automate phpmyadmin to take the data entered by the user on the first page (signup page) from the first table, and assign it to whatever the user types in the fields so that way I know which user did that correct? And so that way each row is unique to the specific user?

Comment: What does this have to do with phpmyadmin? That's a tool for viewing and editing databases by hand, it has nothing to do with writing PHP scripts that process forms.

Comment: you should put the username in a session variable when the user logs in. Use that in the second page, instead of getting it from the form.

Comment: Alright- I kinda need this to work the way it is or at least have the principle of coming immediately after the user signs up. I'm not asking for ideas but, besides the missing SQL execution for the class data, is there any other problem you can think of in terms of keeping whatever the user inputs in the class text fields as being assigned to the specific user that typed them?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Do you want to fill in the `uid` input with the username from the first form, instead of letting the user fill it in by hand?

Comment: Yes exactly. I apologize. I only allowed the user to enter it by hand in the first place as a last resort because I wasn't sure how to do that to see if I could solve the problem. Basically I want it so that whatever the user enters in the classes, the program realizes who that data belongs to. Because different outputs depend on the specific user based on the data they gave, I wanted to assign a unique variable so that way the program would know that any data they entered belong to that specific user. I figured the username would make sense- but I'm unsure if there's a better way to do that?

Comment: If you put it in the form, the user can change it to someone else's username, which I assume you don't want to allow. That's why you should use a session variable, they can't change that.

Comment: I've updated the answer to fill in more details, I hope it helps.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Thanks a lot! I would create the session variable as part of the register/sign up script correct? Or would I only put it in the login script for when the user logs into their account after they've already created one?

Comment: It would be in the login script, but some sites automatically login when the user registers, so you could do it there, too.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a go. Even if it doesn't work I can tell you its much better than not having any plan of action at all. Again, thanks a lot!